# Windows continually reboots when connected to network

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit computer here that continually crashes and reboots when it's plugged in via the ethernet cable.
It'll get to the windows start screen but stuck on [Please wait...] before restarting. No beeps or BSOD, it simply restarts.

This happens in safe mode as well, but only when plugged in.

If I start the computer without connecting to the network it boots up fine and then I can plug the network cable in again and have internet connectivity and everything runs without problems.

The eventlog is filled with Event ID 6005: "The winlogon notification subscriber  is taking long time to handle the notification event (CreateSession)."

As a troubleshooting step I have tried removing the computer from the domain, at which point it started fine even with the ethernet plugged in, but after adding it to the domain again the problems continue.

As an additional troubleshooting step I've ran sfc /scannow which didn't show any problems and also I've reinstalled the ethernet adapters driver which didn't help either.

Google isn't showing anything useful and I'm at a loss as to what to try next.

Comment: Once ran into a similar issue caused by bad/wrong type packets on the network (a test PC brought down others, including production machines!). See http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/2/6/c26893a6-46c7-4b5c-b287-830216597340/TCPIP_Reg.doc for setting Ethernet packet types.